# Using "by-argument" in "outer" data.table to filter "inner" data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I still have some problems understanding the data.table notation. Could anyone explain why the following is not working?

I'm trying to classify dates into groups using `cut`. The breaks used can be found in another data.table and depend on the `by` argument of the outer "data" data.table

```
data <- data.table(A = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                   DATE = as.POSIXct(c("01-01-2012", "30-05-2015", "01-01-2020", "30-06-2012", "30-06-2013", "01-01-1999"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"))

breaks <- data.table(B = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                     BREAKPOINT = as.POSIXct(c("01-01-2015", "01-01-2016", "30-06-2012", "30-06-2013"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"))

data[, bucket := cut(DATE, breaks[B == A, BREAKPOINT], ordered_result = T), by = A]
```

I can get the desired result doing

```
# expected
data[A == 1, bucket := cut(DATE, breaks[B == 1, BREAKPOINT], ordered_result = T)]
data[A == 2, bucket := cut(DATE, breaks[B == 2, BREAKPOINT], ordered_result = T)]
data 
#    A       DATE     bucket
# 1: 1 2012-01-01         NA
# 2: 1 2015-05-30 2015-01-01
# 3: 1 2020-01-01         NA
# 4: 2 2012-06-30 2012-06-30
# 5: 2 2013-06-30         NA
# 6: 2 1999-01-01         NA
```

Thanks, 
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `cut` produces factors and those are not being handled correctly in the `data.table` `by` operation (this is a bug and should be reported - the factor levels should be handled the same way they are handled in `rbind.data.table` or `rbindlist`). An easy fix to your original expression is to convert to character:

```
data[, bucket := as.character(cut(DATE, breaks[B == A, BREAKPOINT], ordered_result = T))
     , by = A]
#   A       DATE     bucket
#1: 1 2012-01-01         NA
#2: 1 2015-05-30 2015-01-01
#3: 1 2020-01-01         NA
#4: 2 2012-06-30 2012-06-30
#5: 2 2013-06-30         NA
#6: 2 1999-01-01         NA
```

Comment: I think it's related to [#967](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/967).